# Install RT5370 usb wifi drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS + raspberry pi 3b

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I'm trying to install the RT5370 usb wifi adapter on raspberry pi 3b but I can't install the drivers. I downloaded the linux drivers from https://www.mediatek.com.es/products/broadband-wifi/rt5370 with:

`$wget https://d86o2zu8ugzlg.cloudfront.net/mediatek-craft/drivers/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022.tar.bz2`

And then unzip them with:

`$tar -xf DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022.tar.bz2`

Then:

`$cd tar DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/`

Any idea what do I need to do? The adapter appears in the system but is not working. When I try to make the drivers it says:

````
$sudo make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools'
/tmp/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /tmp/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-1006-raspi/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-1006-raspi'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl', needed by 'arch/arm/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd-oabi.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/Makefile:293: archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-1006-raspi'
make: *** [Makefile:389: LINUX] Error 2

$lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

$ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:fa:3c:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.56/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 41579sec preferred_lft 41579sec
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fefa:3c31/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68276745/12642499

Comment: The README says: "Supporting Kernel: linux kernel 2.4 and 2.6 series" You have kernel version 5.15. The errors above are an indication that this moldy, rusty old antique won't ever work for your device. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Once we know some details about your exact device, we'll try to find a modern, ARM-suitable driver.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `modinfo rt2800usb | grep 5370` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep rt2`